# In Navigation drawer onitemclicklistener is not working.Drawer is working well

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I am working on an application but In Navigation drawer onitemclicklistener is not working  but Drawer is working well. Logcat shows

```
09-15 16:41:26.568: D/AbsListView(22587): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
09-15 16:41:26.568: D/AbsListView(22587): unregisterIRListener() is called 
09-15 16:41:26.678: D/AbsListView(22587): unregisterIRListener() is called 
09-15 16:41:29.070: D/AbsListView(22587): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
09-15 16:41:29.080: D/AbsListView(22587): unregisterIRListener() is called 
09-15 16:41:29.100: D/AbsListView(22587): unregisterIRListener() is called 
09-15 16:41:29.571: I/net.wigle.wigleandroid.ZoomButtonsController(22587):
```

invoke: onVisibilityChanged listener: org.osmdroid.views.MapView$MapViewZoomListener@41baeee8

and i used this code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mapBeginConfig();
    loadUI();
    mapEndConfig();

    sims = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myItems);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    drawertoggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.drawable.ic_action_overflow, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_Close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

    };
    drawer.setDrawerListener(drawertoggle);


    // sims = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myItems);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sims));
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, sims[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Xml code of the project

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/maincontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#ff8800"
    android:divider="@null" >
</ListView>
```

```
    private void mapBeginConfig() {
        mResourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
        SimpleRegisterReceiver simpleReceiver = new SimpleRegisterReceiver(this);

        // File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        // "Atlas.mbtiles");
        File f = new File(getCacheDir() + "/Atlascities.mbtiles");
        if (!f.exists())
            try {

                InputStream is = getAssets().open("Atlascities.mbtiles");
                int size = is.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                is.read(buffer);
                is.close();

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fos.write(buffer);
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        IArchiveFile[] files = { MBTilesFileArchive.getDatabaseFileArchive(f) };
        MapTileModuleProviderBase moduleProvider = new MapTileFileArchiveProvider(
                simpleReceiver, MBTILESRENDER, files);

        mProvider = new MapTileProviderArray(MBTILESRENDER, null,
                new MapTileModuleProviderBase[] { moduleProvider });

        // this.mOsmv= new
        // com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView(this,(AttributeSet) mResourceProxy
        // );
        this.mOsmv = new MapView(this, 256, mResourceProxy, mProvider);

    }



private void mapEndConfig() {

        this.mOsmv.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        this.mOsmv.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        mOsmv.getController().setZoom(2);

        double lon = 0;

        double lat = 0;



        IGeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lon); // lat lon and not inverse

        mOsmv.getController().setCenter(point);
    }


private void loadUI() {

        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);

        DrawerLayout rl = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);

        this.mOsmv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        rl.addView(this.mOsmv);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your Activity's layout xml.

Comment: I have Edited the xml code Above.

Comment: Is the list filled correctly? Does the drawer work both when you drag, and when you use the ActionBar Button? If yes to both questions, please post the `mapBeginConfig()`, `loadUI()`, and `mapEndConfig()` methods.

Comment: yes they all are working fine .... and please find the code above .

Comment: I just added all three methods. please check.

Comment: I know it's already more than a year late, but I was not able to to it handle clicks with listview either, so I used RecyclerView instead and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `loadUI()` method. You're adding a View, `mOsmv`, directly to the DrawerLayout, causing it to be z-ordered above the drawer, and interfering with click events. The View should be added to the content View - the FrameLayout `maincontent` - like so:

```
private void loadUI()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.maincontent);
    mOsmv.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                              FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                              FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    fl.addView(mOsmv);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . but i want to set my map in drawer layout. IS it possible .

Comment: What do you mean? In the drawer itself?

Comment: Actually i want this map to be shown in drawer layout. and in drawer list i want to set cities, roads . when a user tap on cities map in drawer automatically changes... are you getting me?

Comment: You mean you want the map as the main View, and the drawer with the list slides out over the map?

Comment: That's what this does. The FrameLayout within the DrawerLayout holds the main View. Did you try it?

Comment: no not yet !! How do i do this. please let me know . i used relative layout but every this showing error.

Comment: Don't use RelativeLayout. Use FrameLayout, like in the answer. Look at the layout xml you've posted. The main content is a FrameLayout.